# How to have an ImageView with corners rounded and bordered while using setClipToOutline

Tags: android, xml, imageview, border, rounded-corners

following up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30692466/11054243), how can i achieve the same but including a border that runs smoothly around the clipped `ImageView`.

I have tried using this as a background drawable for the `ImageView` with red borders and `imageView.setClipToOutline(true)`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <corners
        android:radius="35" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#E42323" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp" />
</shape>
```

when not using an image as `Android:src`
 [it works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vmwj.jpg).

but when i use `Android:src` [the borders are clipped as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nakb8.jpg).

**note:** I know one can use a `FrameLayout` with `ImageView` as a child and set the background drawable to the `FrameLayout` but [that's just asking for issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56099209/11054243).

Comment: have you try use two image? first the image with the dish and second the image with round borders

Comment: @FranciscoBarrios your suggesting is similar to the note i stated above, i even think it's cleaner to use `FrameLayout` rather than an `ImageView` to hold the round borders

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't think this is a solution you expected but as there was no easy solution I could find for the question instead came up with a funny workaround if API level >= 23, but since it works thought I'll share it incase it helps someone.

Basically, set the same drawable used as background and set it as

```
android:foreground="@drawable/background"
```

you still need to set background in order for `setClipToOutline` to clip the drawable properly, and foreground will create an overlapping border on the outside.

Even though foreground makes use of `FrameLayout` but since its for the same `ImageView` didn't find any issues with animations, they seem to work fine with it.

Comment: Can confirm, this solution does work, haven't tested animations but it should be fine as well, still it has 2 caveats one is that it demands API >= 23 and the other is that if one is already using a foreground drawable then it has to be edited to have the same shape as the background drawable file

Comment: @EvilNeo somehow I hadn't noticed your comment yet. Yes, as you mentioned API>=23 is a limitation but regarding the foreground it can be anything not necessary the same as background. But `setClipToOutline` clips based on the background frame, so setting a foreground with greater size will make it move outside the clipped imageview, but smaller ones are fine. And as borders for rounded corners was the requirement hence, the suggestion of having both same.